# User-placed phone call from app sends app to background

Tags: android

My app is meant to be used while on the phone and it has pre-programmed buttons for placing calls to key people.

The problem is when a call is initiated, the phone goes to foreground rendering app unavailable.  How to continue phone call but have app come back to  foreground automatically ?

So far I have a phone state listener which is working fine, and I use it to fire an intent to my main activity when phone ringing is detected like this,

```
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        startActivity(i);
```

Its not clear what is happening with this.  It seems like MainActivity is getting restarted ( or resumed ?), several times actually, but foreground stays unchanged in the phone activity.

Comment: Can you please post your code, or an example that demonstrates the problem? Also add what you've tried to solve it so far and where exactly you're stuck. These might help: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: So far I have a phone state listener which is working fine, and I use it to fire an intent to my main activity when phone ringing is detected, like this      Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);